# Why is my mesh so tiny when I port it to UE4?

Tags: export

I'm using metric degrees 0.01000 and my export FBX settings are scaled to 1.00 but when I open up the mesh in UE4 it looks like this. [image]

I circled the tiny speck so you could see him. Any help?

[image]

Comment: How tall is your mesh in blender when you left click on its head and read the 3D cursor's location in the right panel (hit 'N' if its not visible) under "3D Cursor?" Your world scale settings are correct.

Comment: I edited in all the values in the op. Is that what you were looking for? I don't see the height of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, your problem is that the dimensions of your mesh are *tiny!* A mere 1.6074cm tall—this is why it is so small in UE4. I would scale the character by about 100 times. A quick way to do this is to type 'S' and then '100' on your keyboard. After which you should apply the rotation and scale at the very least. I usually also apply the transform. **Note:** make sure you are in object mode and apply the transforms to the armature *and* the meshes of your character. In Blender 2.79 you have to do it one-by-one.

[image]

If you have multiple meshes in blender it can be tricky to measure them all together. One way I do it is by clicking on the top of the character's head: the 3D cursor will be placed there, and then in the right panel you'll be able to see the height of your character. It should definitely be somewhere between 1m - 2.2m tall for a humanoid character.
[image]